# Could using local.xml lead to another outcome than using one of the default layout .xml files?

Tags: layout, blocks, local.xml, ce-1.9.1.0

> **EDIT:** I decided to rephrase my original question, trying to make it a more general question.

I'm trying two options to achieve the same result, but they turn out differently... I'm working in Magento's DEFAULT package and apart from the two options that I will describe below, everyting else in my configuration is left the same.

Here are my two options:

- **Option 1: Using `catalog.xml` to apply a change**

  I copied `app/design/frontend/BASE/default/layout/catalog.xml` to
  `app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/layout/` and changed line
  285 from:

  ```
  <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
  ```

  into this:

  ```
  <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
      <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
      <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
  </block>
  ```

  This option 1 leads to the following result (the result that I need)

  [image]
- **Option 2: Using `layout.xml` trying to apply the same change**

  I have not copied and modified `catalog.xml` but instead created `app/design/frontend/DEFAULT/default/layout/local.xml` which is fully working. In this file I have added the following code:

  ```
  <layout>

      ....

      <PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>

          <reference name="product.info.options.configurable">

              <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
              <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />

          </reference>

      </PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>

  </layout>
  ```

  In my view (please correct me if I'm wrong) this is the only correct way to add the block instances `product.info.options.configurable.renderers` and `product.info.options.configurable.after` to the block instance `product.info.options.configurable` (which in this **Option 2** comes from `app/design/frontend/BASE/default/layout/catalog.xml`).

  This option 2 however leads to the following result (not the result that I need)

  [image]

I have checked everything multiple times and this really sums up my two options which lead to different results. I would expect them to lead to the same result (unless the code I added to `local.xml` is incorrect).

So my question basically comes down to this: Could it be possible that using `local.xml` leads to another result than doing the exact same thing by using one of the default layout .xml files (e.g. `catalog.xml`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I haven't checked for your case, so the answer is more general.*

> Could it be possible that using local.xml leads to another result than doing the exact same thing by using one of the default layout .xml files (e.g. catalog.xml)?

Yes.

Because the loading order of the files is changed. If you try to `<reference>` a block which doesn't exist yet, you can't do anything with it. No `<action>`, no new `<block>` inside, etc.

To avoid this, you have a few options:

1. use another layout handle, which is processed later.
2. `<depend>` on the module which creates the block, so your file is loaded after `catalog.xml`.
3. Use local.xml which is loaded last.

Comment: Thank you @Fabian, this explains a lot. Your 3rd option to use `local.xml` is actually my preferred option. I am trying this in my **2nd option**. If `local.xml` is loaded last, then `product.info.options.configurable` should already exist when trying to put the two `<blocks>` inside. Still this doesn't work the way I want to. Does this automatically lead to the conclusion that there must be an error in the code of my `local.xml` file after all?

Comment: IF the block is loaded inside the same layout handle or BEFORE, yes, the block should exist. To know this, the only way is to dig into code with xdebug

Comment: Yesss!! I finally got this figured out and working now, thanks to your answer explaining about the loading order. The problem was actually in another .xml file which was probably loading after `catalog.xml`, but before `local.xml`. This file was trying load new `<blocks>` inside `product.info.options.configurable.renderers` and `product.info.options.configurable.after`, and those `<blocks>` didn't exist until they were created in `local.xml`. Thank you very much @Fabian!

Comment: Note also another difference other than order - local.xml merges it's contents into the theme XML, overwriting any referenced nodes, whereas any layout.xml (eg catalog.xml) file that is found in a theme will completely replace the parent layout of the same name.

Comment: This happens everywhere. Names are unique through the whole theme.